# Getting Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError when calling coroutine inside workmanager

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm getting below crash only on samsung J7(Android 8) device, when I run coroutine inside workmanager.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class 'com.example.myapplication.SyncAndSaveWork' does not implement interface 'kotlin.d.f' in call to 'java.lang.Object kotlin.d.f.fold(java.lang.Object, kotlin.g.a.m)' (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.internal.y' appears in base.apk)  
   at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ThreadContextKt.threadContextElements(ThreadContextKt.java:60)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuation.<init>(DispatchedContinuation.java:29)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher.interceptContinuation(CoroutineDispatcher.java:99)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.ContinuationImpl.intercepted(ContinuationImpl.java:112)
   at kotlin.coroutines.intrinsics.IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt.createCoroutineUnintercepted(IntrinsicsKt__IntrinsicsJvmKt.java:137)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(CancellableKt.java:26)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.java:109)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.java:158)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.java:54)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(BuildersKt.java:1)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.java:47)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(BuildersKt.java:1)
   at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:85)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**My Worker class:**

```
    class SyncAndSaveWork(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {

    @Volatile
    lateinit var latch: CountDownLatch

    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        Log.d("SyncAndSaveWork", "$exception handled !")
        latch.countDown() 
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        latch = CountDownLatch(1)
        syncData()
        latch.await()  
        Log.d("SyncAndSaveWork", "Finished")
        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        print("After task")
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun syncData() {  // error at this line I guess
        Globle.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            performTask()
            Log.d("SyncAndSaveWork", "Done")
        }
    }

    private fun performTask() {
        Global.launch(Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler) {
            delay(2000) // implementation excluded for bravity
            print("Task compeleted")
            Log.d("SyncAndSaveWork", "Compeleted")
            latch.countDown()
        }
    }
}
```

**Configuration and scheduling workmanger inside Application class:**

```
    class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        var constraints = with(Constraints.Builder()) {
            setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        }.build()

        var request = with(OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncAndSaveWork::class.java)) {
            setConstraints(constraints)
            addTag("SyncAndSaveWork")
            setInitialDelay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        }.build()

        WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWork()
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's happening only on certain devices, am I doing something wrong? Please help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Nope it didn't solve, But I think here is a catch, " Worker.doWork() is a synchronous call—you are expected to do the entirety of your background work in a blocking fashion and finish it by the time the method exits. If you call an asynchronous API in doWork() and return a Result, your callback may not operate properly." - from docs.